# Prove that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_{i}) \subseteq \mathscr P (\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i})$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\{A_{i} | i \in I\}$ is an indexed family of sets.  Prove
>   that $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_{i}) \subseteq \mathscr P
> (\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i})$

My attempt:

Let's denote $\{A_{i} | i \in I\}$ as $\mathcal F$.

Let $x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_{i})$. It implies that there is at least one set, call it $B$, such that $B \in \mathcal F$ and $x \subseteq B$. $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$ (or $\bigcup \mathcal F$) is the set containing all elements of all sets in $\mathcal F$. Since $B \in \mathcal F$, it follows that $x \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$. And by definition of a power set, we can conclude that $x \in \mathscr P (\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i})$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\forall x \bigl(x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_{i}) \implies x \in \mathscr P (\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i})\bigr)$, or in other words, $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_{i}) \subseteq \mathscr P (\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i})$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: The beggining is a little confusing. I would avoid using "$\mathcal{F}$" and "$B$", and instead just use the index set $I$: "*Let $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)$. It implies that there is at least one index $i_0$ such that $x\in\mathscr{P}(A_{i_0})$, which means that $x\subseteq A_{i_0}$. Since the set $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is the set containing all elements of all the sets $A_i$, then it contains all elements of $A_{i_0}$ and, in particular, all elements of $x$, which means that $x\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. And by definition of a power set[...]*" (the rest is ok).

Comment: Personally I prefer the notation $\cup\mathcal F=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ above  $\bigcup\mathcal F=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. IMHV $\cup$ is an *operator* on sets characterized by: $x\in\cup a\iff x\in b$ for some $b\in a$. In that context $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is then an abbreviation of $\cup\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

You could also prove on forehand that: $$A\subseteq B\implies\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$$

Then based on $A_j\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ for every $j\in I$ it can be concluded that $\wp(A_j)\subseteq\wp(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)$ for every $j\in I$.

And the final result follows easily.

Answer (score 2):

This seems correct. In general,

> **Proposition.** If $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of sets such that $A_i \subset B$ for all $i$, then $\bigcup_i A_i \subset B$.

*Proof*. Take $x \in \bigcup_i A_i$. Therefore there exists $j \in I$ such that $x \in A_j$ and thus $x \in B$ by hypothesis. $\square$

> **Proposition.** Given $A \subset B$, we have $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$.

*Proof.* If $C \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $C \subset A \subset B$, which says that $C \in \mathcal{P}(B) \ \square$.

Now we can put this all together: each set $A_j$ is contained in $\bigcup_i A_i$, and thus we have that $\mathcal{P}(A_j) \subset \mathcal{P}(\cup_i A_i)$ for all $j \in I$. By the first proposition, this implies $\cup_i \mathcal{P}(A_i) \subset \mathcal{P}(\cup_I A_i)$.