# To prove that $ \bigcup_{i \in I} \wp(A_i) \subseteq \wp (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i ) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove that $ \bigcup_{i \in I} \wp(A_i) \subseteq \wp (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i ) $

**My Attempt   :**

Let $ A \in  \bigcup_{i \in I} \wp(A_i) $.

So $\exists i \in I (A \in \wp (A_i))$

i.e $\exists i \in I (A \subseteq (A_i))$

Let $ y \in A$ be arbitrary element of A

$\exists i \in I (y \in A_i)$

$ y \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$

So $ A \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i $

i.e $ A \in \wp (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) $

Is this correct ? Thank you very much

PS $ \wp $ denotes power set

Comment: Where do you think that you may have had a gap?

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308374/prove-that-bigcup-i-in-i-mathscr-pa-i-subseteq-mathscr-p-bigcup-i

Comment: @AsafKaragila i think it is okey but i need to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, but the way it is written is a bit clumsy. It is better to not use too much quantifiers. Here is how I would write the proof:

Let $A \in \bigcup_{i \in I} P(A_i)$. Then there is $k \in I$ with $A \in P(A_k)$, which means $A \subseteq A_k$. But since $A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, we have $A \subseteq  \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ and thus $A \in P(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i)$.